# Query document count by multiple ranges returning range start/end with matching element count

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I've been trying to create a query on documents like these:

```
[
    {
        "timestamp": new ISODate('2020-01-01T00:00:00'),
        "objectId": "Id_A",
        "locationId": "Location_A"
    },
    {
        "timestamp": new ISODate('2021-01-01T00:00:00'),
        "objectId": "Id_A",
        "locationId": "Location_A"
    },
    {
        "timestamp": new ISODate('2022-01-01T00:00:00'),
        "objectId": "Id_A",
        "locationId": "Location_B"
    },
    {
        "timestamp": new ISODate('2021-01-01T00:00:00'),
        "objectId": "Id_B",
        "locationId": "Location_B"
    },
    {
        "timestamp": new ISODate('2022-01-01T00:00:00'),
        "objectId": "Id_A",
        "locationId": "Location_A"
    }
]
```

given multiple "and" queries, I want to count the matching documents per range

```
[$or: [
    { $and: [{
        "timestamp": {$gte: new ISODate('2020-01-01T00:00:00'),
                      $lt: new ISODate('2020-12-31T00:00:00'),
        },
        "objectId": "Id_A",
        "locationId": "Location_A"}]},
    { $and: [{
        "timestamp": {$gte: new ISODate('2020-01-01T00:00:00'),
                      $lt: new ISODate('2022-12-31T00:00:00'),
        },
        "objectId": "Id_A",
        "locationId": "Location_A"}]},
    { $and: [{
        "timestamp": {$gte: new ISODate('2022-01-01T00:00:00'),
                      $lt: new ISODate('2022-12-31T00:00:00'),
        },
        "objectId": "Id_A",
        "locationId": "Location_B"}]}
    ]
]
```

I want to map the counts to a result structure that looks like this

```
[
    {"objectId": "Id_A", "locationId": "Location_A", "rangeStart:": new ISODate('2020-01-01T00:00:00'), "rangeEnd": new ISODate('2020-12-31T00:00:00'), "count": 1},
    {"objectId": "Id_A", "locationId": "Location_A", "rangeStart:": new ISODate('2020-01-01T00:00:00'), "rangeEnd": new ISODate('2022-12-31T00:00:00'), "count": 3},
    {"objectId": "Id_A", "locationId": "Location_B", "rangeStart:": new ISODate('2022-01-01T00:00:00'), "rangeEnd": new ISODate('2022-12-31T00:00:00'), "count": 1},
]
```

Aggregations I looked at so far:

- bucket
- facet
- group

But I still can't figure it out.
What would your approach be?

**Update 1**
The rangeKeys are not assigned correctly with the solution I derived from @Takis suggestion:

I get the following result:

```
{ 
    "_id" : {
        "objectId" : "objectA", 
        "locationId" : "locationA", 
        "rangeKey" : "UUID2", 
        "count" : 1.0
    }
}
```

while I expect the following result:

```
{ 
    "_id" : {
        "objectId" : "objectA", 
        "locationId" : "locationA", 
        "rangeKey" : "UUID1",
        "count" : 1.0
    }
}, {
    
    "_id" : {
        "objectId" : "objectB", 
        "locationId" : "locationA", 
        "rangeKey" : "UUID2",
        "count" : 0.0
    }
}
```

This is the query I built

```
db.createCollection("object_location_tracking")
db.getCollection("object_location_tracking").insertMany([
    {
        _id: "1",
        locationId: "locationA",
        objectId: "objectA",
        timestamp: ISODate("2020-01-01T00:00:00Z")
    },
    {
        _id: "2",
        locationId: "locationB",
        objectId: "objectA",
        timestamp: ISODate("2020-01-01T00:00:00Z")
    },
    {
        _id: "3",
        locationId: "locationA",
        objectId: "objectB",
        timestamp: ISODate("2019-01-01T00:00:00Z")
    },
    {
        _id: "4",
        locationId: "locationB",
        objectId: "objectB",
        timestamp: ISODate("2020-01-01T00:00:00Z")
    }
]);
db.getCollection("object_location_tracking").aggregate(
    [
        { 
            "$match" : { 
                "locationId" : "locationA", 
                "$or" : [
                    { 
                        "$and" : [
                            { 
                                "objectId" : "objectA"
                            }, 
                            { 
                                "timestamp" : { 
                                    "$gte" : ISODate("2020-01-01T00:00:00.000+0000")
                                }
                            }, 
                            { 
                                "timestamp" : { 
                                    "$lt" : ISODate("2022-01-01T00:00:00.000+0000")
                                }
                            }
                        ]
                    }, 
                    { 
                        "$and" : [
                            { 
                                "objectId" : "objectB"
                            }, 
                            { 
                                "timestamp" : { 
                                    "$gte" : ISODate("2020-01-01T00:00:00.000+0000")
                                }
                            }, 
                            { 
                                "timestamp" : { 
                                    "$lt" : ISODate("2022-01-01T00:00:00.000+0000")
                                }
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        }, 
        { 
            "$group" : { 
                "_id" : { 
                    "objectId" : "$objectId", 
                    "locationId" : "$locationId", 
                    "rangeKey" : { 
                        "$switch" : { 
                            "branches" : [
                                { 
                                    "case" : { 
                                        "$and" : [
                                            { 
                                                "$gte" : [
                                                    "$timestamp", 
                                                    ISODate("2020-01-01T00:00:00.000+0000")
                                                ]
                                            }, 
                                            { 
                                                "$lt" : [
                                                    "$timestamp", 
                                                    ISODate("2022-01-01T00:00:00.000+0000")
                                                ]
                                            }, 
                                            { 
                                                "objectId" : "objectB"
                                            }, 
                                            { 
                                                "locationId" : "locationA"
                                            }
                                        ]
                                    }, 
                                    "then" : "UUDI2"
                                }, 
                                { 
                                    "case" : { 
                                        "$and" : [
                                            { 
                                                "$gte" : [
                                                    "$timestamp", 
                                                    ISODate("2020-01-01T00:00:00.000+0000")
                                                ]
                                            }, 
                                            { 
                                                "$lt" : [
                                                    "$timestamp", 
                                                    ISODate("2022-01-01T00:00:00.000+0000")
                                                ]
                                            }, 
                                            { 
                                                "objectId" : "objectA"
                                            }, 
                                            { 
                                                "locationId" : "locationA"
                                            }
                                        ]
                                    }, 
                                    "then" : "UUID2"
                                }
                            ], 
                            "default" : "0"
                        }
                    }, 
                    "count" : { 
                        "$sum" : 1.0
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    ], 
    { 
        "allowDiskUse" : true
    }
);
```

Comment: Clarity:  You have specific date ranges (which yes are overlapping, that's OK) and specific `locationId` and `objectId` lookups?   In other words, `Id_A` is given as an input?   What happens if `Id_C` is in the collection?   Would it be ignored?

Comment: try to fix your question for example the 2 documents in the expected output, has the same value in all 4 fields except the count, i think its mistake, also the dates are not formated in ISO format,string is not valid in your `$and` queries. I think you need a `$group`  something like [this](https://cmql.org/playmongo/?q=6254ce5df7e3c64c6511e180) but i am not sure, maybe it will help you, if you are still stuck fix the question if you can with working sample data, and expected output.

Comment: `$facet` can fulfill the query requirements - you can only try and see.

Comment: @Takis your answer pointed me to the right direction, thanks a lot :)
Feel free to post it as a full reply and I'll mark the question solved

Comment: objectB and locationA cannot pass because the date is 2019 fails from the first match, but also in the $and of group you should use aggregate operators i think. This for example { "objectId" : "objectB"} for aggregation is just a literal document not a filter, you need the aggregate operator $eq

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As hinted at in the comments, `$facet` will do the trick.  Note the use of year-only constructors for `ISODate` for simplicity.  The `$project` and `$unwind` are not absolutely necessary because they are a formatting convenience only per the OP.  There will only be a single doc coming out of `$facet` which will be converted into three and only three discrete docs for the ranges so it is not a performance hit.

```js
db.foo.aggregate([
    {$facet: {
        "first_bucket": [
            {$match: {"objectId":"Id_A",
                      "locationId":"Location_A",
                      "timestamp": {$gte: new ISODate('2020-01-01'),
                                    $lt: new ISODate('2020-12-31')}
                     }},
            {$count: "N"}
        ],

        "second_bucket": [
            {$match: {"objectId":"Id_A",
                      "locationId":"Location_A",
                      "timestamp": {$gte: new ISODate('2020-01-01'),
                                    $lt: new ISODate('2022-12-31')}
                     }},
            {$count: "N"}
        ],

        "third_bucket": [
            {$match: {"objectId":"Id_A",
                      "locationId":"Location_B",
                      "timestamp": {$gte: new ISODate('2022-01-01'),
                                    $lt: new ISODate('2022-12-31')}
                     }},
            {$count: "N"}
        ]
    }},
    {$project: {X: [
        {"objectId":"Id_A",
         "locationId":"Location_A",
         "rangeStart": new ISODate('2020-01-01'),
         "rangeEnd": new ISODate('2020-12-31'),
         "count": {$first: '$first_bucket.N'}
        },
        {"objectId":"Id_A",
         "locationId":"Location_A",
         "rangeStart": new ISODate('2020-01-01'),
         "rangeEnd": new ISODate('2022-12-31'),
         "count": {$first: '$second_bucket.N'}
        },
        {"objectId":"Id_A",
         "locationId":"Location_B",
         "rangeStart": new ISODate('2022-01-01'),
         "rangeEnd": new ISODate('2022-12-31'),
         "count": {$first: '$third_bucket.N'}
    }
    ]
    }},
    {$unwind: '$X'},
    {$replaceRoot: {newRoot: '$X'}}
]);
```

UPDATE

`$first` is an operator available on v>=4.4.  To make this solution work v<4.4, change the `count` expression in the `$project` from `$first` to:

```js
 "count": {$arrayElemAt:['$the_bucket.N',0]}
```

A slightly more interesting variation is to use `$group` in the `$facet` expression.  This will produce more entries in the buckets but has the advantage of hardcoding only the date ranges.

```js
db.foo.aggregate([
    {$facet: {
        "first_bucket": [
            {$match: {"timestamp": {$gte: new ISODate('2020-01-01'),
                                    $lt: new ISODate('2020-12-31')}
                     }},
            {$group: {_id: {objectId: "$objectId", locationId:"$locationId"},
                      N: {$sum:1}}}
        ],
        "second_bucket": [
            {$match: {"timestamp": {$gte: new ISODate('2020-01-01'),
                                    $lt: new ISODate('2022-12-31')}
                     }},
            {$group: {_id: {objectId: "$objectId", locationId:"$locationId"},
                      N: {$sum:1}}}
        ],
        "third_bucket": [
            {$match: {"timestamp": {$gte: new ISODate('2022-01-01'),
                                    $lt: new ISODate('2022-12-31')}
                     }},
            {$group: {_id: {objectId: "$objectId", locationId:"$locationId"},
                      N: {$sum:1}}}
        ]

    }}
]);
```

Comment: Thanks :) 
How can I flatten the resulting facet structure to something like this
{
    "first_bucket": 0,
    "second_bucket": 1
}

I guess it's a sample projection but I can't get it right

Comment: Answer updated to match exact output structure desired by OP.

Comment: Thanks for updating it with the structure I initially thought of for response mapping.
However, it would be more efficient in terms of data transfer size to not return all the given query parameters but only an ID for each range which my Java application generates and then maps back to the POJOs.

So I asked another question because my result mapping approach does not work: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71861699/alternative-result-projection-that-works-on-mongodb-4-2-x

Answer (score 1):

Query

- you can add one `$match` as first stage to keep only the valid ranges
  (this can use index also)
- group on objectId and locationId and conditional range
- i didn't tested the bellow query because i dont have sample data, if doesn't work and you are stuck, if you can add sample data and expected output

*`$facet` could be used but facet has those problems (test it to see what is better for your query)

- doesn't use index (even if match is the first stage)
- runs the pipeline multiple times, 1 time per field

```js
aggregate(
[{"$group":
   {"_id":
     {"objectId":"$objectId",
      "locationId":"$locationId",
      "range":
       {"$switch":
         {"branches":
           [{"case":
               {"$and":
                 [{"$gte":["$timestamp", ISODate("2020-01-01T00:00:00Z")]},
                   {"$lt":["$timestamp", ISODate("2020-12-31T00:00:00Z")]}]},
              "then":
               {"rangeStart":ISODate("2020-01-01T00:00:00Z"),
                "rangeEnd":ISODate("2020-12-31T00:00:00Z")}},
             {"case":
               {"$and":
                 [{"$gte":["$timestamp", ISODate("2020-01-01T00:00:00Z")]},
                   {"$lt":["$timestamp", ISODate("2020-12-31T00:00:00Z")]}]},
              "then":
               {"rangeStart":ISODate("2020-01-01T00:00:00Z"),
                "rangeEnd":ISODate("2020-12-31T00:00:00Z")}},
             {"case":
               {"$and":
                 [{"$gte":["$timestamp", ISODate("2020-01-01T00:00:00Z")]},
                   {"$lt":["$timestamp", ISODate("2020-12-31T00:00:00Z")]}]},
              "then":
               {"rangeStart":ISODate("2020-01-01T00:00:00Z"),
                "rangeEnd":ISODate("2020-12-31T00:00:00Z")}}],
          "default":"out-of-range"}}},
    "count":{"$sum":1}}},
 {"$project":
   {"_id":0,
    "count":1,
    "objectId":"$_id.objectId",
    "locationId":"$_id.locationId",
    "range":"$_id.range"}}])
```

Comment: Thank you :) I'm still encountering a problem - I will extend my original question with another section ;)

Comment: extended question with current solution, actual and expected result ;)

Comment: This solution will not allow for the overlapping date ranges to be grouped separately.  It puts each doc into one range slot, the first one encountered in the `branches`.